# Applications of real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I understand the defenition and theorems in real analysis.But i am try to know the applications of real analyais and how to apply. what are the applications of Real analysis?

Comment: As a general rule, *all math is applicable to real life*. For more esoteric mathematics, those applications are not obvious, and even may be presently unknown, but I believe they are still there. The basics of real analysis are not esoteric, and form the basis of most of classical physics, who applicability is obvious. The more picayune details (such as definitions of numbers, definitions of various integrals, etc.) give us confidence that our calculations are well-defined, and thus the results are not just our imagination.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you choose to pick on Real Analysis?

More generally, I think someone like Lebesgue might say that mathematical analysis is needed in order to develop say less obvious math.

Also what kind of lazy nonconstructive bums just close a thread like this? This forum is so lame.